# Как добавить в .gitignore все папки одного имени кроме одной подпапки

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

У меня четыре модуля. В каждом - папка `target`, которую я игнорирую в файле `.gitignore`. Появилась необходимость отслеживать одну из подпапок, но никак не поучается ее вернуть. Вот что у меня в файле:

```
# Default ignored files
/shelf/
.idea
*.iml
target
!/model/target/generated-sources/annotations/*
/httpRequests/
```

А вот та самая папка, которую мне нужно отслживать(она помечена желтым - это не то, что нужно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно поправить? Буду благодарна, заранее спасибо!

Comment: А зачем Вам отслеживать сгенерированные файлы?

Comment: Это мета-энтити. Они генерируются hibernatе-ом и нужны для того, чтобы, используя сортировку или поиск при помощи Queries отвязаться от строковых названий полей

Comment: давайте попробуем зайти с другой стороны. а какого эффекта вы, собственно, ожидаете? ну, представьте, что у вас получилось подправить нужным образом файл `.gitignore`. что после этого должно, по-вашему, измениться?

Comment: Не нужно сгенерированный код ложить в систему контроля версий. Это проблема xy.

Comment: А у вас, случайно, директория, в которой лежит `model/`, называется не `/httpRequests/`?